# Nilpotent $4 × 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Find a nilpotent $4 × 4$ matrix with only $-1$ and $3$ as entries.

$\begin{bmatrix}
      -1 & -1 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
    3 & -1 & 3& -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix I came up with, but I don't think it works. Anyone have a better one?

Comment: How about 4 columns of just $(3,-1,-1,-1)$? Applying it once sends any vector to a multiple of this one, then applying it again kills that vector since its coefficients sum to $0$.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Zero is the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix, so, up to permutation you know that its main diagonal must be $$\begin{pmatrix}3&&&\\&-1&&\\&&-1&\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$ The matrix must also be singular, which means that it’s going to have linearly dependent columns. Can you fill out the rest of the matrix so that this is true? (There’s more than one way to do that.)